# MySQL error - I don't understand what it is saying

Tags: sql, mysql

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `job_listing_has_employer_details` (`job_listing_id`, `employer_details_id`)
VALUES (6, '5')
```

Error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`job_listing_has_employer_details`, CONSTRAINT `job_listing_has_employer_details_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`employer_details_id`) REFERENCES `employer_details` (`id`))

What does this mean? The two ID's I am inserting into the table exist.

Answer (score 1):

It means it can't find '5' in the `id` column of the `employer_details` table. If there is a 5 in that column of that table, then maybe the data is numeric, so must be passed without quotes. If so, try:

```
INSERT INTO `job_listing_has_employer_details` (`job_listing_id`, `employer_details_id`) VALUES (6, 5)
```

Comment: I am casting the value into an int with PHP and I am still getting said error

Comment: What is the output of `select count(*) from employer_details where id = 6`?

Comment: 6 is the job_listing_id not the employer_details_id

Comment: So, let's try again. What is the output of `select count(*) from employer_details where id = 5`?